# Configuring Hostname

Tags: web-services, networking, dns, hostname, dedicated

I wanted to know how to properly configure the hostname of my server I for example I have this domain "gamemode.com.br" I set the hostname only "gamemode.com.br" or "server.gamemode.com.br" ( I will use multiple servers connected to the same network ), Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning to use multiple servers, it may be a good idea to have different host names, as you have suggested - "server.gamemode.com.br", or use the roles of each server as a way to name them e.g. "master.gamemode.com.br", "maps.gamemode.com.br".